# click action not performed due to Softkeyboard enable(Hide the keyboard also its not working) but test is passed

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I tried get login into my account using this capabilities

Android version-7.0
Appium version - 1.71
java-client - 5.8.0
selenium-standalone server -3.52.0

1.first username, password entered successfully using selenium
2.while entering password soft keyboard was enabled but I did hide keyboard also
3.But I clicked login but it is passed but where it is clicked I don't know
(I thought it might be soft keyboard issue)

Please let me know why the action not performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a native app, hybrid, web? Paste what you got until now...

Anyway, if you searched the element before the software keyboard is hidden and you try to click it after the keyboard is not longer visible... Then you could have a problem.

1. Add a delay for a few seconds and search again for the element and try clicking
2. What are you using to hide keyboard? I guess -> driver.hide_keyboard() method? Have you tried doing click at X, Y coordinates like 10,10 that are obviously out of the keyboard(for example...). Or have you tried simulating terminal back button? -> driver.back()
3. If 1. and 2. are not working, why don't you try with capabilities -> 'unicodeKeyboard' and 'resetKeyboard' setted to true?

You will need to provide more information to be able to help. Then I will edit my answer with code and examples

Comment: Thank so much,its working fine for me using desired capabilities(unicodeKeyboard,resetKeyboard)      capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
  
  capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);